# Is reading of a file is lazily evaluated in Apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the below code,

```
Val df1 = sparkSession.read().json("abc.json")

Val df2 = df1.where("point > 200").limit(10)

df2.count()
```

**My first question is**, when the first line is evaluated and my data is read into df1? does that happen when count action is called?

**My second question is**, does the data that is saved to df1 will be available in df1 till the execution of program ends and I can use it to perform any other operations as well?

```
Ex -   Val df3 = df1.where("point > 100")

       df3.count()
```

Answer (score 3):

Spark has two things, operations and actions. All the operations are lazy and don't get executed until you call actions (i.e. count, show, save)

In your case action is **count**. So once you execute **df2.count()** the following things happen:

1. spark reads the file and creates dataframe, df1
2. it applies your logic and creates a new dataframe, df2
3. finally shows your count.

**Second Question**
No, Data is not saved to a dataframe like normal programming language. This is lazy evaluation. So an action triggers all the steps.

In your case when you call **df3.count** the following things happen:

1. spark will read file again and create dataframe, df1
2. your logic will be applied and new dataframe d3 will be created.
3. and finally a count will be shown.

If you are planning to have couple of operation on single dataframe you can save that dataframe using **cache** function. Which will put the dataframe into memory and so operations before that won't be performed again.

so what you should do is:

```
val df1 = sparkSession.read().json("abc.json")
df1.cache() // all the data are saved to memory (or disk )

val df2 = df1.where("point > 200").limit(10)
df2.count() // However cache happens only after first action. So this line will execute reading file and caching it. 

val df3 = df1.where("point > 100")
df3.count() // This won't read the file again.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have one follow up question. if I use same filtering operation in both query i.e, where("point > 200") and I do not cache the complete df1 as you did but I cache dataframe after filtering in first query like this df1.where("point > 200").cache().limit(10). now, when I call df2.count(), filtered dataframe will be cached.
Now, In the end, when I run
val df3 = df1.where("point > 200") and df3.count(), will it again read the file from storage or the cached dataframe will be used or both of these things will happen one after the other ??

Comment: `cache` is like saving a state, so when you execute the code which requires that state. it will be used direclty.  so in you'r cache. filter condition `where("point > 200")` will be executed only one and saved. Next time when it needs to use that data. it just use saved data.